# C - How to check if number entered

Tags: c, string, numbers

How to simply and correctly check if user enters a number and not a char or string in C language? I've tried to write some loops containing:

```
if (scanf("%d",&number)=1)
```

but they never work or end. The loop should end when a number is entered.

Comment: I don't think such thing should even compile.

Comment: @user: increase the warning level of your compiler and **mind the warnings**

Answer (score 4):

It should be

```
if (scanf("%d", &number) == 1) // Notice the two ='s, not just one
```

A single `=` is the assignment operator, a double `==` is the equality test.

Comment: but scanf is not an lvalue, it shouldn't be assignable.

Comment: @MByD yeah I know, but it's what he said he used, so that's the info I have to go on. Maybe his compiler is just really bad. I just don't have the time to go second-guessing people on everything.

Comment: It is unlikely that it's the compiler fault. Anyway, it was not criticism, only wondering.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
for (scanf(" %d", &number); (number < -100 || number > 100); scanf(" %d", &number)) {
    printf("you didn't enter a valid number, try again >");
}
```

Comment: Well, remember that `isdigit` takes a character and tells you if the character is one of the characters `0` through `9`.

Comment: Yeah it would help to know the context. But also we don't know that he doesn't want numbers larger than 9 or smaller than 1, so testing `number >= 1 && number <= 9` might not be good. You really almost have to check the return value of `scanf` to do this.

Comment: the context is not important. I just have several programs which need this verification, if entered value is a number (not only a digit). For example the number can be from -100 to 100. And if user enters a letter or something else then there should show a message that there is entered an incorrect value and user has to enter the value again. And this should continue until a number is entered.

Comment: @user646263 was there a problem with my answer? If so, you should let me know so I can attempt to improve it.

Comment: it still does not fully work. It should print
`printf("you didn't enter a valid number, try again >");`
when a letter or word is entered too. for example "a" or "abc".

Comment: that is what it should do, if a char is changed to it's ascii equivalent I do not know how to detect that, unless you scan for chars and check if they are numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Your line should simply be:
`if (scanf("%d",&number)){`

If anything other than a number is entered, it will result in: `if(0){`, instead of `if(1){`

Answer (score 0):

Does this suit your context:

```
char ch;int g;
for(ch=getc(stdin);isalpha(ch);ch=getc(stdin))
{
printf("\nenter numbers only");
while(isalpha(getc(stdin))){}
}
ungetc(ch,stdin);
scanf("%d",&g);
printf("number entered  %d",g);
```